# How to access object in multidimensional array in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic, I am using a List to store an array of objects.  However, I haven't figured out how to access a particular object once I have added it to my list.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio

```
Private Results As New List(Of Object)

Dim Results As Object()

Dim CaseStatus as String = "Closed"

...

Results.Add(New Object() {CaseStatus, FlagsStr, OBTotal, OBPaid})

MessageBox.Show(Result(0).ToString)
```

Displays: System.Object[]

I have also tried `MessageBox.Show(Results(0,0).ToString)`, but don't get the expected results.

Comment: `Results` is a `List(Of Object)`, and that `Object` is an `Object[]` - you don't have a multidimensional array, you have a list of arrays. If `Result(0)` gives you the first array in the list, then `Result(0)(0)` gives you the first item in the first array in the list.

Comment: Far too much Object, always favor a named type.  Write a class that has CaseStatus, FalgsStr etc properties.  It can override ToString() to produce an appropriate representation.

Comment: Mathieu, you are correct.  However, Result(0)(0) produces an error.

Comment: @JoeDann - Must we guess what that error is?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the error.  It is a late binding error.  Yes, I know I can turn on Option Strict, but was trying to find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

When you can `.ToString` on an object you get the fully qualified name of the object unless the class overrides `.ToString`. Creating a class and a List (Of T) gives you easy access to any of the properties of the class.

```
Public Class ProjectCase
    Public Property CaseStatus As String
    Public Property FlagsString As String
    Public Property OBTotal As Decimal
    Public Property OBPaid As Decimal

    Public Sub New()
        'include a default constructor
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(cs As String, fs As String, total As Decimal, paid As Decimal)
        CaseStatus = cs
        FlagsString = fs
        OBTotal = total
        OBPaid = paid
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{CaseStatus}, {FlagsString}, Total = {OBTotal}, Paid = {OBPaid}"
    End Function
End Class

Private Results As New List(Of ProjectCase)

Private Sub OPCode()
    Results.Add(New ProjectCase("Closed", "Some string", 74.36D, 22D))
    MessageBox.Show(Results(0).ToString)
    MessageBox.Show(Results(0).CaseStatus) 'or any property of your class
End Sub
```